# Remove attributes from XElement

Tags: c#, xelement

I am trying to remove some attributes from xml document. Here is what I tried:

```
private void RemoveEmptyNamespace(XElement element) {
            foreach (XElement el in element.Elements()) {
                if (el.Attribute("xmlns") != null && el.Attribute("xmlns").Value == string.Empty)
                    el.Attribute("xmlns").Remove();
                if (el.HasElements)
                    RemoveEmptyNamespace(el);
            }
        }
```

But it doesn't work. When I debug inside the method, attribute is removed, but when the method is fully executed, no changes were saved. The document is the same. I suppose that is because of foreach loop, but I don't see other way of looping through.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the whole code I am using:

```
        var file = new FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.Open);
        var doc = new XDocument();
        doc = XDocument.Load(savedFile);
        RemoveEmptyNamespace(doc.Root);//method above
        file.SetLength(0);
        doc.Save(file);
        file.Close();
```

EDIT2: Now I have tried to achieve the same goal by going line by line and replacing strings. And nothing happens!!! The document is still the same. If somebody had similar problem, please help me.

Comment: instead of the first if, try this: "if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(el.Attribute("xmlns"))"

Comment: @Henk Holterman Not saved means that the document is the same as it was before method call, as I described in the question.

Comment: Problem is in saving than, not in method you have described. Just use doc.Save(fileName) instead. file.SetLengh - what for?

Comment: @Henk Holterman My xml is .csproj file, but that shouldn't matter. I am really confused.

Comment: @Ales I am setting length to 0 because I don't want to append text to existing document, but to clear it first. I am using doc.Save...

Comment: It's not. I am making some changes to it, save it, and after saving the xmlns="" appears everywhere. But I close the file normally, and than the stated code is called.

Comment: I have checked that too. It's unbelievable, probably something stupid, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found what the actual problem was. XDocument class was adding blank xmlns every time I changed something in the document! That is why I couldn't remove them. It behaves like that because it needs namespace definition for every XElement you create. So I solved the problem by doing so. The only thing that needs to be done is adding namespace to the XElement name. Something like this:

```
XNamespace nameSpace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";
var subType = new XElement(nameSpace + "SubType"); // strange but true
```

I hope this will help someone with the same problem. Thanks everybody for your answers.

Comment: hey there! When you added that namespace, did it remove the attribute xmlns from the element or did it keep it? I tried your solution but it still displayed the attribute. Please tell me about your results, thanks.

Comment: @Hallaghan I was working with this long time ago, but I think that the namespace needs to stay if you are serializing wpf elements for example (which is what I was doing here) or if you are doing something similar. If you are creating XDocument manualy from scratch, no namespace is needed (from my expirience).

Comment: thanks for the tip. Your solution has resolved my problem. Cheers :)

Comment: note that it's not `string` but `XNamespace nameSpace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";`

Answer (score 7):

This work for me:

```
private static void RemoveEmptyNamespace(XElement element)
{
    XAttribute attr = element.Attribute("xmlns");
    if (attr != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(attr.Value))
        attr.Remove();
    foreach (XElement el in element.Elements())
        RemoveEmptyNamespace(el);
}
```

Only difference is that i'm counting with xmlns attribute in root element too.
But it really works, trust me

whole test:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new XElement("root", new XElement("t", new XAttribute("xmlns", "")), new XAttribute("aaab", "bb"));
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        RemoveEmptyNamespace(x);
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }

    private static void RemoveEmptyNamespace(XElement element)
    {
        XAttribute attr = element.Attribute("xmlns");
        if (attr != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(attr.Value))
            attr.Remove();
        foreach (XElement el in element.Elements())
            RemoveEmptyNamespace(el);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

return the XElement from method and assign back it to variable, or pass as reference

```
private XElement RemoveEmptyNamespace(XElement element) {
        foreach (XElement el in element.Elements()) {
            if (el.Attribute("xmlns") != null && el.Attribute("xmlns").Value == string.Empty)
                el.Attribute("xmlns").Remove();
            if (el.HasElements)
                el = RemoveEmptyNamespace(el);
        }
      return element;
    }
```

Comment: What do u mean I changed wrong method? How does it matter if attribute.remove is void?

Answer (score 0):

```
 string xml = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\xml.txt");
            XDocument wapProvisioningDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            foreach(var ele in wapProvisioningDoc.Elements().Elements("characteristic"))//characteristic
            {
                var attribute = ele.Attribute("target");
                if (attribute != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(attribute.Value))
                {
                    attribute.Remove();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are deleting the attribute from a read-only object created in the "foreach" loop. You must delete the instance child from "elements", not from "el".

I think a better and easy option is the use of a "for" for this task. in C# maybe something like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < element.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
        {
            if (element.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["xmlns"] != null && element.ChildNodes[i].Attributes["xmlns"].Value == String.Empty)
            {
                element.ChildNodes[i].Attributes.RemoveNamedItem("xmlns");
            }
            if (element.ChildNodes[i].HasChildNodes)
            {
                element.ChildNodes[i].RemoveAll();
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: don't create a new object, create a read-only object but it references to interation object.

Comment: I cannot access XElement by index, only by name. Your example is for XNode I think.

Comment: According the lenguage specification 8.8.4 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664754%28v=vs.71%29.aspx "The iteration variable corresponds to a read-only local variable with a scope that extends over the embedded statement." so yes, is reference, but you can't modify it.